# sympy dot product results in a list

Tags: python, matrix, sympy, dot-product

I have two sympy matrices, `U` and `B`:

```
>> U
<< Matrix([
   [1.0,   0,   0,   0],
   [  0, 1.0,   0,   0],
   [  0,   0, 1.0,   0],
   [  0,   0,   0, 1.0]])
>> B
<< Matrix([
   [sqrt(2)/2,  0.5*sqrt(2)*I,             0,          0],
   [        0,              0, 0.5*sqrt(2)*I,  sqrt(2)/2],
   [        0,              0, 0.5*sqrt(2)*I, -sqrt(2)/2],
   [sqrt(2)/2, -0.5*sqrt(2)*I,             0,          0]])
```

Applying dot product to them results in a list, instead of a 4x4 matrix:

```
>> U.dot(B)
<< [0.5*sqrt(2),
    0,
    0,
    0.5*sqrt(2),
    0.5*sqrt(2)*I,
    0,
    0,
    -0.5*sqrt(2)*I,
    0,
    0.5*sqrt(2)*I,
    0.5*sqrt(2)*I,
    0,
    0,
    0.5*sqrt(2),
    -0.5*sqrt(2),
    0]
```

In contrast, numpy looks like doing the right thing:

```
>> numpy.dot(sympy.matrix2numpy(U),sympy.matrix2numpy(B))
<< array([[0.5*sqrt(2), 0.5*sqrt(2)*I, 0, 0],
   [0, 0, 0.5*sqrt(2)*I, 0.5*sqrt(2)],
   [0, 0, 0.5*sqrt(2)*I, -0.5*sqrt(2)],
   [0.5*sqrt(2), -0.5*sqrt(2)*I, 0, 0]], dtype=object)
```

What am I doing wrong? Is this the expected behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike NumPy, in SymPy, `dot` means the dot product of vectors. It's designed so that you can get the dot product of two row or column vectors without having to worry about using `.T`, but perhaps the laxness in shape is a bit much here, as it's literally taking the dot product of `list(U)` and `list(B)`.

It is probably being too lax here. I've opened a [SymPy issue](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/13765) for this. It would be more correct for SymPy to raise an exception in this case.

As @Wrzlprmft correctly pointed out, SymPy uses `*` to multiply matrices (or `@` if you are using Python 3.5 or greater).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation and for submitting the issue!

Answer (score 2):

SymPy uses the `*` operation for the multiplication of matrices, i.e., you want to use:

```
U*B

# Matrix([
# [0.5*sqrt(2),  0.5*sqrt(2)*I,             0,            0],
# [          0,              0, 0.5*sqrt(2)*I,  0.5*sqrt(2)],
# [          0,              0, 0.5*sqrt(2)*I, -0.5*sqrt(2)],
# [0.5*sqrt(2), -0.5*sqrt(2)*I,             0,            0]])
```

As you can see, the elements are the same as your list, but with the desired structure.